# Looping Promises of request calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-request

I'm downloading a pdf which is splitted into pngs in a server. I manage to download one page separately when I use only one promise, but it's not working when chaining those promises so i can download them all. When it reaches the "bucket.upload" bit throws a "no such file" error. Again, it works smoothly if i don't chain the promises, but i need it to work for a non linear number of pages.

I'm sure the loop is not done right.

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');


mkdirp('tmp').then(() => {


var pages = 5;

let promises = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {

promises.push(getPdfPage(i));}
return Promise.all(promises)}).then(() => {

console.log('All files created');
// Uploading the file.
return bucket.upload('tmp/page1.png'), { destination: 'newupload.png', metadata: metadata });


});




function getPdfPage(p) {

  var aux = 'tmp/page.png';

  return new Promise(resolve => {request('http:www.example.com/image'+ p + '.png', function (error, response, body) {     

// adding page number to file
var chars = aux.split('');
chars.splice(-4, 0, p);
aux = chars.join('');

}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(aux)).on('finish', resolve);})
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Firebase.  Are you trying to run this in Cloud Functions?

Comment: Is newupload.png meant to be a string?

Comment: @DougStevenson yep! i'm trying to upload it into a bucket in the last bit of code

Comment: @iSZ it is! i changed it when posting the question, fixing it now

Comment: Where's your function definition?  Nothing here looks particular to Firebase at all.  You can't just upload random node.js code and expect it to work correctly.

Comment: it's only a part of the code, not the whole thing. just what matters - the promises loop. the rest is working correctly and it's too big to post.

Comment: R U sure the order of things that happens is the one you expect? I did not dig into the code, but I have seen this "missing resource" error many times in event based programming when the actual order of things happening is different than the developer's idea.

Comment: the logs tell me it is.. and the upload part should only work when the rest finishes. i can't really see the files on the tmp firebase folder so i can't check if they are actually created or not, but it works with only 1 promise.